# Fastify: How to call remote url from .get/.post

Tags: javascript, fastify

Currently working on fastify encounter a question that haven't got the solution jet.

This is the code currently using. **users.js**

```
async function routes(fastify, options) {
  // GET /users/:id
  fastify.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    // Create a remote request to any url for testing
    // https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
  });
}

module.exports = routes;
```

Id like to make a request to the  following URL and return its response.
this is how I'm trying to do it.

```
async function routes(fastify, options) {
  // GET /users/:id
  fastify.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    // Create a remote request to any url for testing
    // https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
    const response = await got;
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json);
        res.send({
          id: req.params.id,
          title: json.title,
          completed: json.completed,
          userId: json.userId
        });
      }).catch = err => {
      console.log(err);
    };
  });
}

module.exports = routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
Install axios or [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

Add this line on code start.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
```

Fetch sample code to integrate with fastify .get

```
async function routes(fastify, options) {
  /* GET /users/:id and fetch from remote server */
  fastify.get("/:id", async (request, response) => {
    // Create a remote request to any url for testing
    const remoteURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
    fetch(remoteURL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        const payload = {
          id: request.params.id,
          title: data.title,
          completed: data.completed
        };
        response.send(payload);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
}

module.exports = routes;
```